# cfpresentation does not retain format of div in PowerPoint

Tags: css, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am creating a PPT using the `<cfpresentation>` tag using ColdFusion 9.0.1.  The presentation gets generated, however the information within it is not getting displayed as it is coded.  I am using `<div>` tags to create columned output.  However, when it is generated in PPT, the format is ignored and the data is displayed as full text lines with the right side column being displayed directly under the left side column information.  Below is css and html code within the `<cfpresentation>`.  Any ideas on how to make the code and presentation show exactly as coded, i.e. columned output?

```
content {
clear: both;
width: 500px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
overflow:hidden;
margin-left:20px;
margin-right:20px;
}
#contentLeft {
float: left;
width: 250px;
margin-left:10px;
}
#contentRight {
width: 250px;
margin-left:55%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<cfpresentationslide>

     <div id="content" style="font-size:10px;">
        <div id="contentLeft">
           <span style="font-weight:bold;">&bull;&nbsp;&nbsp;#title# - </span>
           <span style="font-weight:normal;">#backupinfo#</span><p></p>
        </div>

        <div id="contentRight">
           <span style="font-weight:bold;">&bull;&nbsp;&nbsp;#title# - </span>
           <span style="font-weight:normal;">#backupinfo#</span><p></p>
        </div>
     </div>   

</cfpresentationslide>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that the `<cfpresentationslide>` tag cannot pull the CSS styles from your style sheet. Try using inline styles within the `<cfpresentationslide>` tag instead for `content`, `contentLeft`, and `contentRight`.

Something like this:

```
<cfpresentationslide>

 <div style="font-size:10px; clear:both; width:500px; padding-bottom:10px; overflow:hidden; margin-left:20px; margin-right:20px;">
    <div style="float:left; width:250px; margin-left:10px;">
       <span style="font-weight:bold;">&bull;&nbsp;&nbsp;#title# - </span>
       <span style="font-weight:normal;">#backupinfo#</span><p></p>
    </div>

    <div style="width:250px; margin-left:55%;">
       <span style="font-weight:bold;">&bull;&nbsp;&nbsp;#title# - </span>
       <span style="font-weight:normal;">#backupinfo#</span><p></p>
    </div>
 </div>   

</cfpresentationslide>
```

Alternatively you might be able to create a separate HTML file with your desired format then include that using the `src` attribute of the `<cfpresentationslide>` tag. Perhaps that will allow the use of an external style sheet but I am just guessing.

[Link to the online documentation for cfpresentationslide](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-790f.html)

Comment: I used the inline styles and that worked.  I guess you were right about the <cfpresentationslide> not being able to pull the CSS styles.